# JVMTI class not prepared

Tags: java, jvm, javaagents, jvmti

I'm writing a native Java agent using JVMTI that goes over all the methods of all the loaded classes. Unfortunately many classes seem not yet prepared and therefore `GetClassMethods` returns `JVMTI_ERROR_CLASS_NOT_PREPARED`. I am registering a `ClassPrepare` event callback but that seem to be called only for very few classes. Simplified (minus all the error handling and deallocation) my code looks like this

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnAttach(JavaVM* jvm, char *options, void *reserved) {

     jvmtiEnv *jvmti;
     jint class_count;
     jclass* classes;
     jint method_count;
     jmethodID* methods;

     (*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void**) &jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_11);
     (*jvmti)->GetLoadedClasses(jvmti, &class_count, &classes);
     for (int i = 0; i < class_count; i++) {
       jclass klass = classes[i];
       // here a lot of time JVMTI_ERROR_CLASS_NOT_PREPARED is returned
       jvmtiError err = (*jvmti)->GetClassMethods(jvmti, klass, &method_count, &methods);
     }
```

The agent is attached dynamically to a running JVM using JCMD and the JVMTI.agent_load command. I did try to register a class prepare callback using:

```
jvmtiEventCallbacks callbacks;
(void)memset(&callbacks, 0, sizeof(callbacks));
callbacks.ClassPrepare = &callbackClassPrepare;
(*jvmti)->SetEventCallbacks(jvmti, &callbacks, (jint) sizeof(callbacks));
(*jvmti)->SetEventNotificationMode(jvmti, JVMTI_ENABLE, JVMTI_EVENT_CLASS_PREPARE, (jthread) NULL);
```

But this ended only being called for very few classes.

How can I get the JVM to prepare the loaded classes so that `GetClassMethods` returns `JVMTI_ERROR_NONE`?

So far I have only tested with JDK 17.0.1 with Shenandoah GC.

Comment: So what is the question? I don't see any question marks here.

Comment: How can I get the JVM to prepare the loaded classes so that `GetClassMethods` returns `JVMTI_ERROR_NONE`?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to "prepare" classes. This is done automatically when needed, specifically, at link time. It's absolutely normal when some classes are loaded but not yet linked.

Comment: So I simply won't be able to call `GetClassMethods` on loaded classes that are not yet linked. There isn't anything I should do about this, just register callbacks for `ClassPrepare` and `ClassLoad`?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Very well. If it's not too much to ask could your turn the comment into an answer so I can mark it and other people can find it more easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a normal situation when some classes are loaded but not [linked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4). You don't need to do anything to prepare classes manually - JVM does this automatically when needed. JVM Specification guarantees the classes is completely prepared before it is initialized. As soon as it happens, JVM TI `ClassPrepare` event is fired.

So in order to get all available `jmethodID`s you'll need:

1. Iterate over all loaded classes, ignoring possible `JVMTI_ERROR_CLASS_NOT_PREPARED`.
2. Set `ClassPrepare` event callback and call `GetClassMethods` in it.